# Posting JSON with http post and other data to php page

Tags: php

I have a php page and I want to be able to submit a JSON string, and a few other  fields back to itself (http post) so I can do some server-side PHP work.  Since I'm new to PHP I see a lot of ways of doing this, but some of them aren't working the way I wanted because I wanted to post to the actual page itself so it can do some backend with a lot of session data, page specific data depending where the page came from, etc before moving on.  For this reason AJAX is out of the question.

My JSON string is being created in javascript using JSON.stringify off an object array that I have created.  Right now I just output my JSON using..

```
var output = JSON.stringify(objectTable);
console.log(output);
```

And the JSON is created perfectly no issues there.  I have a few input fields on the page as well that I need to be posted back.  Up to this point (before I needed to send the JSON) I just been doing..

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" onsubmit="return validateData()" method="post">

    <input type="text" id="itemName" value="page1" />
    <input type="text" id="itemColor" value="red" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

This of course works perfectly fine, but now with the JSON I'm starting to wounder if I should be doing something else?  I know I could maybe create an  and then when my javascript runs and does the JSON.stringify then just set the input value to the JSON.  However these seems kind of "cheap" and doesn't seem to be the best practice to me.  I also worry if there are any downfalls to doing this method such as special character issues or anything?  Is there a different, more logical, or professional way I should be doing this?

Comment: as I cant see where the JSON would go, I'm confused

Comment: everything on the page would be posted to the <form> as listed above.  Which is itself.  So if the data is on "test.php" then it just does a submit to itself "test.php" as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simple, Works, Totaly okay method

So if the `objectTable` object needs to be sent to the same PHP script at the same time as the other data in the form, then just create a hidden field in the form and when the user hits submit, set the hidden value to that of the object.

```
<input id='secretSHhhhhh' type='hidden' value='false'>
```

Then in JS (I am using some jQuery notation because I am lazy).

```
$('form').on('submit',function() {
    /* ... stuff ... */
    $('#secretSHhhhhh').val(JSON.stringify(objectTable));
});
```

Otherwise if you want to send the json encoded object to a PHP script that is kind of independent of the form, then I recommend using ajax.  Once again I am using jQuery because it is easy, especially for ajax.  In this case I am using the `post` subset of ajax, but there are many more options in the jQuery library.

```
$.post("somePage.php", objectTable,function( stuffThePageReturned ) { // No need to stringify
    console.log(stuffThePageReturned);
});
```

#### My preferred method

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var PostData = {};
    PostData.itemName = $('#itemName').val();
    PostData.itemColor = $('#itemColor').val();
    // === Any extra fills from input elements === //
    PostData.objectTable = objectTable;

    $.post("somePage.php", PostData,function( stuffThePageReturned ) {
        console.log(stuffThePageReturned);
    });
});
```

Comment: so going the hidden input method would still be considered a perfectly fine route to go?  Didn't know if that was a "cheesy" way to do what I was trying to accomplish or not.  Like if other programmer saw that I went with this route they wouldn't question why I didn't do something else when trying have the data posted back to the same page its located on (hence the <form> example above)

Comment: @eqiz Ok so what it comes down to is that this is on the client.  So EVERYTHING can be manipulated by the end user.  This is no better, in that sense, than any other solution.  **That being said:** I prefer to do something a little bit different, that yes, I believe is cleaner.  I will add this to my answer in a couple minutes.  ***caveat***, I only know how to do this using jQuery, so if you want a lighter weight solution you will need to find the proper native JS.

Comment: Thank you for doing that.  I would like to do the best way possible if anything.  I very much appreciate your added cleaner solution.